# The past perfect use. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: tenses, past-perfect

> Now she knew he would be unstoppable. That day, there had been no doubts inside of him when he had wielded his sword.

Is this correct use of the past perfect tense in the second sentence, considering the context?

Comment: //That day, there had been no doubts inside of him when he had wielded his sword'. // There are two past perfect tenses in this sentence. It can be refined as "That day, there had been no doubts inside of him when he wielded his sword." Here, 'having doubts' is an action longer than 'wielding the sword', hence this refinement suggested.

Comment: Thank you! But doesn't it clash with the fact that 'when he wielded his sword' is also describing the moment that is set further in the past than 'Now she knew he would be unstoppable'?

Comment: I think 'wielding' and 'having doubt' wouldn't be simultaneous. It was at a time he had no doubts that he wielded...

Comment: "...had no doubts _inside_ him" seems a little clunky.